# parse text file using xml template

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net, parsing

Not quite sure how to word this.  Looking for info on VB.net or C#, either one will do.

I'm trying to make a generic file parser that will use an XML file to define the file layout (field names, data types, delimiter type, file type, etc).

The idea is to use this in programs that have differing input file layouts and types (delimited/flat file) without having to modify and recompile.  Would like it this way as occasionally the local offices change the format (add/remove fields) and it breaks production until the code is recompiled, re-tested etc.

Unfortunately, as I said, I have no idea how to even look this up.

Any help pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'd consider to change input file to be xml (or to have corresponding xml).

In this case - you can create your xsd schema, and validate it using xsd.

You can even send this xsd to your offices to validate there inputs **before** they send it to you.

One other way it to use SSIS

Comment: Unfortunately we're lucky with what we get....it's a life insurance company and we're the home office, so the local offices give us whatever their admin system can give us.  it's odd but that's what we have.

Comment: Updated my answer - did you check optuon of using SSIS?

Comment: We've used SSIS, Informatica, and another proprietary ETL tool, problem is some of the programs tend to be rather long and complex (lot of forward/backward record looking) and each is limited in it's own way.  We're looking to do a higher level language (VB or C#) that will give us more flexibility.  One of the problems is SOX auditing controls we have to have that none of what we've used handle well.  SSIS is good, but difficult to maintain after a certain complexity, informatica is just trash, same with proprietary one.  That code is easy, its the "universal" parser I'm having trbl with.

Comment: Occasionally the local offices will muck up an extract, either change the delimiter, add/remove fields, rearrange columns etc (usually by opening a delimited file in excel then re-saving it).  Due to agreements (in house political ones) we have to process the files in 2-3 days for valuation, so that means altering code, re-test, re-deploy, all quickly and on top of other "priority" work.  For simple things I'd like to just alter an XML to add/remove/change fields not used in any calculations to make things simpler on everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You can use for that an open source solution called FinTp.